# Segmentation fault : _IO_feof (fp=0x0) at feof.c:35

Tags: c

When I run the output program using gdb from the terminal it always ends with a segmentation fault at this function.
But running this with eclipse debugger works fine.

```
ssize_t
read_from_file(char *arg, unsigned char *buf, size_t max_buf_len) {
  ssize_t result = 0;
  FILE *f = fopen(arg, "r");
  int c;
  while (!feof(f)) {
    size_t bytes_read;
    bytes_read = fread(buf, 1, max_buf_len, f);
    if (ferror(f)) {
      result = -1;
      break;
    }

    buf += bytes_read;
    result += bytes_read;
    max_buf_len -= bytes_read;
  }

  fclose(f);
  return result;
}
```

Error message from gdb

```
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
_IO_feof (fp=0x0) at feof.c:35
35      feof.c: No such file or directory.
```

I tried using alternatives to `feof()` Like

```
while((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
```

But I get the same results

```
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
_IO_getc (fp=0x0) at getc.c:37
37      getc.c: No such file or directory.
```

Does anyone know where this error is originating from?

Comment: It says so right at the error message `fp = 0x0`, the passed file pointer is NULL.

Comment: See [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `while (!feof(f))` is always a bug because in C the end-of-file condition is only detected **after** an attempt to read, never **before**.

And then, you violated two of the [ten commandments](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ten-commandments.html) (2 and 6), by not checking the return value from `fopen`, which can be NULL and cause segmentation faults when you use the file pointer.

Yes, no matter what you tell us about your IDE and debugging, you got a NULL pointer from `fopen()` and passed it to `feof()`, which is literally in the error message you got and the question title: `fp=0x0`.

Comment: Surprisingly simple this worked like a charm ! and thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

You should check `fopen` return value.

Comment: I know this is strange part because I have the same args on eclipse debugger and the fopen function returns the correct pointer to the file when I step through the code

Comment: @yrekik I would bet you pass a relative file path and not a full absolute path. In that case it depends on your working directory which might be different in your debugger and your command line.